Show that the equation $(-i+2j+3k) \times x = i + 5j$ has no solutions for the unknown vector $x$.
The problem:
Show that the equation $(-i+2j+3k) \times x = i + 5j$ has no solutions for the unknown vector $x$.
What I have tried (shoutout to phunkypharaoh):
$x = ai+bj+ck$
$(-i+2j+3k) \times x = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 2 & 3\\a & b & c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 3\\b & c\end{bmatrix}i-\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 3\\a & c\end{bmatrix}j+\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 2\\a & b\end{bmatrix}k =$
$=(2c-3b)i-(-c-3a)j+(-b-2a)k=(2c-3b)i+(c+3a)j+(-b-2a)k$
Where do I go from here? Have I even begun right?

You have to put $2c-3b=1;\space c+3a=5;\space -b-2a=0$ which is not compatible (try, for example, to get the absurde $0=9$).

I was suspecting this was the way I was to continue. And what method am I expected to use to figure out that it is not compatible? I can think of one way which is isolating c in the second equation, see what that equals in terms of a. Then isolating the b in the third equation, getting it in terms of a and then putting it in the first equation and also isolating c in the very same equation. I have two c's in terms of a's, which dont equal each other.

It's too brute force-y, isnt it?

The cross product of two vectors $u$ and $v$ is a third vector that is perpendicular to both $u$ and $v$. But $i + 5j$ isn't perpendicular to $-i + 2j + 3k$. We can check this using the dot product:
$$(i + 5j) \cdot (-i + 2j + 3k) = 1 \cdot -1 + 5 \cdot 2 + 0 \cdot 3$$
$$=9$$
Which isn't $0$, so they can't be perpendicular.

Continuing your “brute force” evaluation of the cross product:
$$(-i+2j+3k) \times x = i + 5j$$
$$(2c - 3b)i - (-c - 3a)j + (-b - 2a)k = i + 5j$$
This gives us the system of equations:
$$-3b + 2c = 1 \tag{1}$$
$$3a + c = 5 \tag{2}$$
$$-2a - b = 0 \tag{3}$$
Equation (3) gives us $b = -2a$.  Substituting into (1) gives:
$$6a + 2c = 1$$
$$3a + c = \frac{1}{2}$$
But this contradicts equation (2), which gives $3a + c = 5$.  Thus, there are no solutions to the system of equations.
